# Delete View With Confirmation Prompt - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to delete compoany with Confirmation Prompt. I dont want to redirect to new template.

```
class CompanyDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company/company_confirm_delete.html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just overload the `get` method:

```
class CompanyDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = Company

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Just to note that it is poor practice to allow a "GET" HTTP operation to mutate data. Pertinent discussion here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server.
This is the underlying reason why confirmation prompts are needed. There also exist plenty of examples out there showing how using simple links to mutate data is a Bad Idea - web crawlers, for example, can decimate a site with "delete" links.
The second response is a much better alternative (and still has a popup prompt).

Answer (score 3):

Use JavaScript to show a pop-up when you click the delete button. In that pop-up, there will be a link to your delete view. 
So instead of giving the link in delete button give a confirmation pop-up there and write the link in that pop-up.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  if (confirm("Do you want to delete!")) {
   //go to your delete path
  } else {
  //don't do anything
  }

}
</script>
```

In your button you can call this function like this

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Delete it</button>
```